# SAP HR CATS application

Tags: workflow, sap-hr

How to send the rejection/approval emails to the employee after the manager has approved the time using MSS application (we are using standard TS310000007) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that task specifically, but you have a couple options:

- If it's a standalone task (not part
  of a workflow template) then you
  could extend the CATS business object
  and create a `ZAPPROVE` method that
  sends an email after the approval is
  complete.
- If that task is part of a workflow
  template then you can just copy that
  template to a Z workflow and add an
  email step after the TS31000007 step.